# React jquery-ui not working

Tags: reactjs, jquery-ui

I've been trying to use jquery with react effectively and it's been working out great so far by writing **import $ from 'jquery'** at the top of the corresponding component.

Now, however, I need jquery-ui. To accomplish this, I have run **npm install jquery-ui** and sure enough there is a jquery-ui file in my node_modules. However, if I try to run some jquery-ui method like:

```
$('.SomeClass').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' });
```

I get about 70 errors, the last one being `jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function`. Can anyone help me get jquery-ui running proper?! Thanks a million.

I also tried to change my import to **import $ from 'jquery-ui'**. Then I only get the error `Cannot read property 'version' of undefined`, or else `name.split is not a function` if I try to be fancy using **$(event.currentTarget)**. Hopefully the updated import is a step in the right direction, but mind it could be a red herring.

NOTE: I got `npm WARN react@0.8.0 requires a peer of envify@~0.2.0 but none was installed` when I installed jquery-ui but I don't suppose this has any relevance to my errors.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes, it's in my node_modules. That is enough I suspect, but please let me know if there is some way I need to call it as well.

Comment: Use `import $ from 'jquery'` and `import 'jquery-ui'`

Comment: I'm afraid I already tried that. Sadly, it gives me the same error as when I use `import $ from 'jquery'` on its own.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help, hope you'll find a solution

Comment: @CaseyHofland, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: At the time, I believe I found something saying that React doesn't work with jquery-ui, but that was then. I've been out of the web development game for almost 2 years now.